# Why this :$\int \frac1x =\ln |x|+c$ a common wrong beliefs in mathematics?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I come accross [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27892/51189)  which i didn't understand it even now such that the auther of this answer say's:Perhaps the most prevalent false belief in math, starting with calculus class, is that the general antiderivative of $f(x) = 1/x$ is $F(x) = ln|x| + C$.  This can be found in innumerable calculus textbooks and is ubiquitous on the Web.

However I checked comments there to understand why this statement is false but I can't $?$ In which context this is not true $?$

Comment: Only in the case of a definite intgeral , you can run into problems , namely if $0$ is within the interval $[a,b]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true as far as I'm concerned, because when I work with the function $\frac{1}{x}$ in calculus, I am usually needing it only on the domain of positive real numbers or the domain of negative real numbers.  And I think it should be taught to new calculus students that the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x| + C$ to avoid confusing them with technicalities.

However, [people like this](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/191/035/135.png) would raise a fuss about the fact that the full domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is not connected, and that there are therefore many more antiderivatives than just adding a single constant to $\ln|x|$.

Here is the sense in which it is not true.  On the domain of $(0,\infty)$, the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|+ C$, and on the domain of $(-\infty, 0)$, the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x| + C$.  Therefore, the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$, on the domain of all nonzero real numbers, is

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} \ln|x| + C_1 & \textrm{ if $x > 0$} \\ \ln|x| + C_2 & \textrm{if $x < 0$} \end{cases}$$

for a *pair* of constants $C_1, C_2$.

Comment: +1 For using "this guy"

Comment: How about $$\int_i^1\frac{dx}x=\ln\sqrt{i^2}-\ne \ln|i|-0,i=\sqrt{-1}$$